# Accessing Excel Workbook returns "The resource could not be found."

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api

I'm looking to connect to the Microsoft Graph API and interact with a small Excel workbook on my OneDrive.

I am able to successfully authorize & connect to OneDrive through the Graph API, query my personal OneDrive contents, and I can even find the .xlsx workbook and grab its ID.  A `GET` request to this endpoint is successful:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/recent
```

The response to that above `GET` request includes (some data omitted):

```json
{createdDateTime: "2017-12-13T04:24:57Z", lastModifiedDateTime: "2017-12-13T04:26:09Z"}
id:"{id}"
name:"transactions.xlsx"
```

However, connecting to this "transactions.xlsx" workbook through a graph API call seems to struggle in my web application.  For example a `GET` request here:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{id}/workbook/worksheets('Sheet1')/usedRange
```

returns workbook data successfully through the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#).  But merely copying + pasting that API call into my app then fails with:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "itemNotFound",
    "message": "The resource could not be found.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "7716493f-cc32-413e-b4fa-5855df7ad181",
      "date": "2017-12-13T14:54:43"
    }
  }
}
```

What am I missing about Graph API calls that is allowing my OneDrive queries to pass but the Excel queries to claim `item not found`?

*This is a business Microsoft Graph/O365 account*

Comment: How are you obtaining the Access Token? Which scopes have you requested and which OAUTH grant flow are you using?

Comment: I am using this code sample that I believe connects via Oauth 2.0 https://github.com/microsoftgraph/ruby-connect-rest-sample.  Unsure what scopes I have requested - I can look into that further.

Comment: In your app, does the plain file GET operation (not with `/workbook` but on `/items/{id}`) work? It sounds like the file itself is not resolving. Could you try and update the results?

Comment: Sudhi, those operations work on the graph explorer.  Tried in app and same error quoted in the above question.

Comment: Are you logging in with the same credentials in Graph Explorer and your application?

Comment: yes - i have confirmed that because when I `GET` my recent onedrive files, I'm able to see an updated excel.  It's when I try to access/open that excel file that the response is `itemNotFound`

Comment: graph explorer successfully pulls all data, including excel data, for my account.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with one of the getting started projects for Excel REST to see if you can get desired result? `https://github.com/microsoftgraph?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=excelstarter`.

Comment: I did use this to get up and running https://github.com/microsoftgraph/ruby-connect-rest-sample .  I'm going to try one of the ones you linked, will report back on how that goes.

Comment: The link I included is explicitly for Excel. It should be more relevant for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The response you are displaying for `GET /me/drive/recent` is quite limited. Is there any entry for remoteItem on your results?

If that is the case you need to use a different URL to get the transaction.xlsx file.

```
GET /drives/{remoteItem-driveId}/items/{remoteItem-id}
```

From: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/drive_recent#remarks

If that is not the case, you can also use the following request to find out your folder structure:

```
GET /me/drive/root/children
```

With the results of the above query, you can then use this to retrieve the contents of the folders:

```
GET /me/drive/items/{item-id}/children
```

Once you know the exact location you can use the following to retrieve your workbook:

```
GET /me/drive/root:/{item-path}
```

Obviously if you already know the path you can go directly to the last step :-)

Comment: All of these work using the graph explorer, some do not in the application.  Using the structure from your first suggestion `/drives/{remoteItem-driveId}/items/{remoteItem-id}` this returns an itemNotFound result in my application.  Interestingly, `/me/drive/root/search(q='csv')?select=name,id,webUrl` successfully queries from the application, whereas `/me/drive/root/children` does not.

Comment: @BryanKnouse, in the response from `GET /me/drive/recent`, is there an entry for **remoteItem**?

Comment: No, just an empty "error" response very similar to what's linked in my question.  This call does work for the graph explorer, however.